# Delete the First 3 and last 3 Characters of the Data in the TextBox With Eval and Substring

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring, eval

I want to delete the first 3 and last 3 characters of the data in the textbox with eval. I tried something like the following but it just erased the first character from the beginning.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description").ToString().Substring(1, Eval("Description").ToString().Length - 3).Substring(0, Eval("Description").ToString().Length - 3) %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Substring` usage is wrong. Just one substring is sufface.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description").ToString().Substring(3, Eval("Description").ToString().Length - 6) %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It is working. Well, what should I write to delete the first 3 and last 4 characters?

Comment: Just apply "Eval("Description").ToString().Length - 7".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        Eval("Description").Length > 6 ? Eval("Description").Substring(3, Eval("Description").Length - 6) : "The string is too short!";
```